# Does anyone have a useful mnemonic for implementing Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, mnemonics

Every time I need to implement a comparator, I get stuck trying to remember when I should return -1 and when 1, and I have to look it up.

I mean, obviously -1 is *less*, so it implies that `first` is less than `second`. But whenever I say that to myself, I get that nagging "are you sure?" feeling. I suspect part of my confusion comes from implementing it the other way around whenever I need a descending sort.

What do you use to remember which is which?

Comment: This could be even language-agnostic.

Comment: tuff question - I just remember it by hearth :)

Comment: I predict that now that you've taken the time and effort to write this as a question on this site, you will find out that you no longer have a problem remembering what values you should return. :-D

Comment: Can you clarify in your quesiton whether you are looking for a ascending or descending result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`comparator.compare(a, b) < 0` <==> `a < b`

Comment: For some reason I like this one the best.

Answer (score 11):

I use this simple "substraction" mnemonic:

```
first - second
```

So, if `first` is "less" than `second` you'll get negative result, otherwise - positive or zero if they are equal.

Comment: +0: Unless overflow is a problem in which case `Integer.MIN_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE = 1` ;)

Comment: or the ever so golden `(0 - Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. :-)

Comment: My mind uses Doubles. That's why there is no equality for me and I do usually forget a lot of details :)

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you mean by mnemonic. However, I have had a very similar cognitive dissonance.

I am very visual, so I use the number line (the one I was taught in grade school). I just visualize the negative numbers as "left", 0 as "center" and positive numbers as "right". That the corresponds to the truth: -1 < 0 < 1

Answer (score 2):

I remember the base integer case (pseudocode):

```
int comparator(int a, int b) {
   return a-b;
}
```

So if we give in a small `a` and a large `b` which is the first < last we get a negative result.

I have a more visual memory, so remembering the "structure" of that function is easy and natural for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used to always check the documentation when implementing `Comparator` and `Comparable` interfaces.

**Question: Compare a and b**
Lets first at look ascending order since the descending order will be just the inverse of whatever we do.
*Question can be translated to given two numbers a and b, how would you put them on the number line?*
if a < b, then we will put `a` on the negative side and `b` on the positive side.
else if a = b then we will put both at the center (at 0)
otherwise `b` will be on the negative side and `a` will be on the positive side.

[image]

**Comparator Implementation:**
Here you are comparing `a` to `b`.

```
 @Override
    public int compare(MyClass a, MyClass b) { //always good to rename your variables like this to be consistent 
        return a.f1 - b.f1; 
    }
```

**Comparable Implementation:**
Here you are comparing `this` to `other`.

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass other) { // this is same as compare(this, other)
        return this.f1 - o.f1;
    }
```